# Need to check if point X is in any distance from a line made between 2 dots

Tags: line, distance, angle, dot, points

I am using Sourcepawn, can also understand java ,but I need just a tip, idea to work on

[image] - 2 red dots are end points of the beam. Beam can be in any angles (X,Y). I need to focus on green dot, check the closest distance between orange line (I don't have any points more, just 2 ends) and green dot.

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The closest point will always be on a right angle to the line, that should help somehow

Comment: I think that i have another idea how I should solve it.
Simply I'll send another beam like first one from this point, and check distance between end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Sketch: 3 points]
Given that you want to know the vector `d` with defined points `p1`, `p2` and `p3` you could do the following (vector variables are underlined):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or, in a more code friendly notation (I am using JavaScript here) we represent vectors as arrays with x- and y-values:

```js
const fromP1=(p,i)=>p-p1[i],   // subtract vector p1 from current vector
         dot=(a,b)=>a.reduce((v,p,i)=>v+p*b[i],0); // scalar product
// these are just arbitrary sample point values:
const p1=[1,5,0], p2=[6,2.5,0], p3=[2,2,0];

const a=p2.map(fromP1),         // vector from P1 to P2
  b=p3.map(fromP1),             // vector from P1 to P3
 fa=dot(a,b)/dot(a,a),          // scalar factor for vector a
  c=a.map(p=>p*fa),             // scale vector a by fa
  d=b.map((p,i)=>p-c[i]);       // vector d = vector b - vector c
  
  console.log("vector c:",c);
  console.log("vector d:",d)
```

As a little side note: This method works just as well for 3 (or even more!) dimensions. Simply add further components (=coordinate values) to (*all of*) the vector arrays. The vector functions will automatically work with all defined dimensions.

[image]

If you only want to know the scalar value of the minimum distance then things get a littlie easier:

[image]

```js
const fromP1=(p,i)=>p-p1[i],    // subtract vector p1 from current vector
         dot=(a,b)=>a.reduce((v,p,i)=>v+p*b[i],0); // scalar product
                                // sample point values (3D):
const p1=[1,5,0], p2=[6,2.5,0], p3=[2,2,0];

const a=p2.map(fromP1),         // vector from P1 to P2
      b=p3.map(fromP1);         // vector from P1 to P3

const ab=dot(a,b);

console.log("distance:",Math.sqrt(dot(b,b) - ab*ab/dot(a,a)) );
```

Comment: Impressive explaination. Thank you! I am in trouble with getting scalar for "c".
My code now looks like this :
`float a[3], b[3], c[3], d[3], fa, playerPos[3];

   GetClientAbsOrigin(client, playerPos);
    playerPos[2] = tempBorder.fEndPoint1[2];
    MakeVectorFromPoints(tempBorder.fEndPoint1, tempBorder.fEndPoint2, a);
    MakeVectorFromPoints(tempBorder.fEndPoint1, playerPos, b);
    // ? :()
    ScaleVector(a, fa);`

Format has gone bad, I hope You could see this clearly. :P

Comment: Explaination : 
1. playerPos is our P3.
2. tempBorder.fEndPoint1 is P1 (I am making both heights equals, because I am using X,Y,Z points)
3. I am making vectors for "a" and "b"
4. I am going to scale vector "a", but I don't have a scalar. I don't understand your javascript snippet, and probably I'll need to do it manually. Here's the API: https://sm.alliedmods.net/new-api/vector

Comment: The scale factor `fa` to calculate the vector `c` from `a` (for three dimensions) is: `(ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz)/(ax*ax + ay*ay + az*az)`. So `c=[ax*fa,ay*fa,az*fa]`. `.map()` and `reduce()` are merely parametric ways of doing the same. (You could use `GetVectorDotProduct()` for the dot-product.)